# Parallel capacitance

Tags: switches

[image]

Hi, I'm trying t0 make a H-Bridge from the ground up and I was wondering if there is a way to deal with my Parallel FET's capacitances? is there any tricky way to reduce the capacitance in parallel at the driver?

Comment: TonyStewart is kind to provide an answer to such a seriously flawed schematic. You have many changes to make before this will work.

Comment: Just look at the schematic and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. But you can be more careful in MOSFET select using RdsOn*Ciss product figure of merit (FoM) vs Vds max. Then use R,C,CR (diode) serial impedance to optimize dead-time by skew between rise time and fall time.

You can also find out which MOSFETs have a PTC characteristic with RdsOn so that thermal runaway can be easily avoided.

If you can't find one then you can add a PTC at any trip current and Curie temp from 50 to 125'C in SMD.

Other pitfalls with current shared MOSFETs , especially with current limiters operated at low limits under a short circuit fault condition. See below.

https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND8199-D.PDF